# Provider com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider could not be instantiated while reading from bigquery in Jupyter lab

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery

I have followed this post [pyspark error reading bigquery: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796397/pyspark-error-reading-bigquery-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-spa)

and followed the resolution provided but still getting the same error. Please help.

I am trying to run this using Jupyter lab created using data proc cluster in GCP.

I am using Python 3 kernel (not PySpark) to allow you to configure the SparkSession in the notebook and include the spark-bigquery-connector required to use the BigQuery
Storage API.

```
!scala -version
```

scala version is Scala code runner version 2.11.12 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName('1.2. BigQuery Storage & Spark SQL - Python')\
  .config('spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar')\
  .config("viewsEnabled","true")\
  .getOrCreate()


spark.conf.set("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled",True)


df = spark.read \
  .format('bigquery') \
  .option('table', 'table_name') \
  .load()
```

below is the error, i am getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-bcc65722cf80> in <module>
      1 df = spark.read \
      2   .format('bigquery') \
----> 3   .option('table', 'wmt-rdl-stage.dim_tables.store_dim') \
      4   .load()

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    170             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    171         else:
--> 172             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    173 
    174     @since(1.4)

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o411.load.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryUtilScala$
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.<init>(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:42)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.<init>(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class
```

.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at java.util.Se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please switch to `gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.11.jar`. The number after the `_` is the Scala binary version.